# Savgol filter over dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to apply a savgol filter from SciPy to smooth my data. I've successfully applied the filter by selecting each column separately, defining a new y value and plotting it. However I wanted to apply the function in a more efficient way across a dataframe.

```
y0 = alldata_raw.iloc[:,0]
w0 = savgol_filter(y0, 41, 1)
```

My first thought was to create an empty array, write a for loop apply the function to each column, append it to the array and finally concatenate the array. However I got an error 'TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid'

```
smoothed_array = []
for key,values in alldata_raw.iteritems():
    y = savgol_filter(values, 41, 1)
    smoothed_array.append(y)

alldata_smoothed = pd.concat(smoothed_array, axis=1)
```

Instead I tried using the pd.apply() function however I'm having issues with that. I have an error message: 'TypeError: expected x and y to have same length'

```
alldata_smoothed = alldata_raw.apply(savgol_filter(alldata_raw, 41, 1), axis=1)
print(alldata_smoothed)
```

I'm quite new to python so any advice on how to make each method work and which is preferable would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the filter first create a function that takes a single argument - the column data. Then you can apply it to dataframe columns like this:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
def my_filter(x):
    return savgol_filter(x, 41, 1)
alldata_smoothed = alldata_raw.apply(my_filter)
```

You could also go with a `lambda` function:

```
alldata_smoothed = alldata_raw.apply(lambda x: savgol_filter(x,41,1))
```

`axis=1` in `apply` is specified to apply the function to dataframe rows. What you need is the default option `axis=0` which means apply it to the columns.

That was pretty general but the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) for `savgol_filter` tell me that it accepts an `axis` argument too. So in this specific case you could apply the filter to the whole dataframe at once. This will probably be more performant but I haven't checked =).

```
alldata_smoothed = pd.DataFrame(savgol_filter(alldata_raw, 41, 1, axis=0),
                                columns=alldata_raw.columns,
                                index=alldata_raw.index)
```